# Own "installed" cls/sty files impossible to find with El Capitan

Tags: packages, mactex

I switched to El Capitan and reinstalled MacTex2015. I had some cls and sty files in `~/.texmf/tex/latex/` and it was working just fine previously. Now I cant find a way to make `pdflatex` know about those files. 
I tried to do `sudo texhash`:

```
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

but without success. When I try to compile I keep getting:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `style_cours.sty' not found.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Consider registering to the site, in order to better contribute to it; not only answers count as good contributions, but also questions do: there aren't good answers without good questions!

Answer (score 5):

Installing personal packages or classes in `~/.texmf/tex/latex` has always been wrong.

Under MacTeX the correct place for the personal tree is

```
~/Library/texmf/
```

and it's still the same with El Capitan. Try issuing the shell command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

and the answer will be

```
/Users/<user>/Library/texmf
```

where `<user>` stands for your login name.

If you don't have a `~/Library/texmf` folder, just create it and move there what you had in ~/.texmf`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! it worked perfectly. I dont where I got that "~/.texmf/tex/latex" idea ....

Comment: @Pierre Welcome to TeX.SX!