# MacTeX does not find my local .sty files on El Capitan

Tags: mac, texmf

I have just installed MacTex under El Capitan and put my latex .sty files in the ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex folder, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272744/own-installed-cls-sty-files-impossible-to-find-with-el-capitan), but MacTex still does not find them. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` (followed by return) in a Terminal window? What's the output?

Comment: Thank you egreg, that seems  alright: /Users/Username/Library/texmf.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Can you check whether you have a `ls-R` file in the top level?

Comment: ls -R in ~/Library/texmf gives  (http://imgur.com/7Oy4Huw), all these folders were just created.

Comment: I meant a *file* named `ls-R`; but never mind, it doesn't seem to be there. Now `kpsewhich jegyzet.sty` prints no output?

Comment: It gives: /Users/Username/Library/texmf/tex/latex/jegyzet.sty.

Comment: Well, so it finds it, after all. Can you try compiling your file from the terminal?

Comment: It worked from the terminal, thanks for the tip! So apparently it was something wrong with my sublime text LaTexTools build command, that i could not find. I changed LateXTools settings back to default and now it is working.